# Django formset UpdateView won't let me upload files

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, formset

I'm trying to create an UpdateView view with multiple inline formsets. It's working almost fine as I can add or remove files and images, but for some reason it won't accept any file/image. For example, if I add a second File in a Publication and upload a file, it will return a form_invalid function stating that This field is required next to the FileField. Same thing with images - I can't add any new image or I can't even change any image to another file as it'll say that this field is required. Other than that, I can change all the Publication fields and I can also change File's title, description and version and it'll save properly, but when I add a new File/Image or just change the file it uses, then it won't do anything and it'll just return an invalid form function.

**models.py**

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Tytul', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=('Author'), blank=True, default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Data publikacji', default=datetime.now)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField('Data ostatniej modyfikacji', default=datetime.now)
    description = models.CharField('Opis', max_length=450)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=('Kategoria'), default=0, related_name='publication')
    video = EmbedVideoField(blank=True)

class File(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Tytul', max_length=100)
    version = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Wersja", max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=('Author'), blank=True, default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Data publikacji', default=datetime.now)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField('Data ostatniej modyfikacji', default=datetime.now)
    description = models.CharField('Opis', max_length=450)
    downloads = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    physicalfile = models.FileField('Wrzuc plik', upload_to=randomfilenames, validators=[validate_extension])
    publicationfk = models.ForeignKey(Publication,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files')


class Image(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, related_name='images')
    image = VersatileImageField('Wrzuc obrazek')
```

**forms.py**

```
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['title', 'version', 'description', 'physicalfile',]

class ImgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['image',]

class PublicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'slug', 'category',]

fileformset = inlineformset_factory(Publication, File, form=FileForm, exclude=[],can_delete=True, extra=1)
imageformset = inlineformset_factory(Publication, Image, form=ImgForm, can_delete=True, exclude=[], extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class PublicationEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Publication
    form_class = PublicationForm
    template_name = 'mods/pubedit.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.success_url = reverse('mods:publicationview', args=(self.object.id,))
        return self.success_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublicationEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['pubform'] = PublicationForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            context['fileform'] = fileformset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)
            context['imgform'] = imageformset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['pubform'] = PublicationForm(instance=self.object)
            context['fileform'] = fileformset(instance=self.object)
            context['imgform'] = imageformset(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        pubform = self.get_form(form_class)
        fileform = fileformset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)
        imgform = imageformset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)

        if (pubform.is_valid() and fileform.is_valid() and imgform.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(pubform, fileform, imgform)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(pubform, fileform, imgform)


    def form_valid(self, pubform, fileform, imgform):
        self.object = pubform.save()
        fileform.instance = self.object
        fileform.save()
        imgform.instance = self.object
        imgform.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, pubform, fileform, imgform):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(pubform=pubform,
                                  fileform=fileform,
                                  imgform=imgform))
```

Comment: Do you set form's enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Well, no, I didn't. I completely forgot about it. Thank you so much, I spent hours trying to find what's wrong with my code, meanwhile I forgot about this basic thing, it's working fine now.

Comment: You are welcome. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason is not setting form's enctype attribute.
If you are using form to upload files you shoul set `enctype` attribute like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```